# Error: Timezone "gmt+0200" is not recognized

Tags: node.js, timezone, angular6

I've got a problem.

I'm trying to "transfer" some data from one table to each other through *.js file. Everything goes fine, except one thing. This function shows me:

```
Error: Timezone "gmt+0200" is not recognized
```

This is my function

```
async function submitCompletationCG(database, ulogin, idc) {
  await connectToSpecificDatabase(database);
  const AC_ID = `SELECT * FROM public.cg_actualcompletations WHERE UserLogin = '`+ulogin+`';`;
  let AC_IDs = await client.query(AC_ID);
  const ACC_ID = `SELECT * FROM public.cg_actualcompletationscondensed WHERE UserLogin = '`+ulogin+`';`;
  let ACC_IDs = await client.query(ACC_ID);
  const DEPOT = `SELECT * FROM public.cg_actualdepots WHERE UserLogin = '`+ulogin+`';`;
  let DEPOTs = await client.query(DEPOT);

  let depot_from, depot_to, code_from, code_to;

  for(let Depot of DEPOTs.rows) {
    depot_from = Depot.depot_from;
    depot_to = Depot.depot_to;
    code_from = Depot.code_from;
    code_to = Depot.code_to;
  }

  for(let Completation of ACC_IDs.rows) {  //Transfer all Completations Condensed
    const ACC_Copy = `INSERT INTO public.cg_completationscondensed(
                      id_c, userlogin, barcode, quantity, adate)
                      VALUES ('`+idc+`', '`+ulogin+`', '`+Completation.barcode+`', '`+Completation.quantity+`', '`+Completation.adate+`');`;
    await client.query(ACC_Copy);
    const ACC_Delete = `DELETE FROM public.cg_actualcompletationscondensed
                        WHERE id = `+Completation.id+`;`;
    await client.query(ACC_Delete);
  }

  for(let Completation of AC_IDs.rows) {  //Transfer all Completations
    const AC_Copy = `INSERT INTO public.cg_completations(
                      id_c, userlogin, barcode, quantity, adate)
                      VALUES ('`+idc+`', '`+ulogin+`', '`+Completation.barcode+`', '`+Completation.quantity+`', '`+Completation.adate+`');`;
    await client.query(AC_Copy);
    const AC_Delete = `DELETE FROM public.cg_actualcompletations
                        WHERE id = `+Completation.id+`;`;
    await client.query(AC_Delete);
  }

  const SUB_UArch = `INSERT INTO public.cg_userarch(
                      userlogin, id_c, depot_from, depot_to, code_from, code_to)
                      VALUES ('`+ulogin+`', '`+idc+`', '`+depot_from+`', '`+depot_to+`', '`+code_from+`', '`+code_to+`');`;
  await client.query(SUB_UArch);

  const SUB_DKill = `DELETE FROM public.cg_actualdepots WHERE UserLogin = '`+ulogin+`';`;
  await client.query(SUB_DKill);

  return true;
}
```

Sould I set timezone somewhere in angular files? Or it's problem with database? Forgot to say I'm using PostgreSQL. ADate column is type "timestamp without time zone", earlier it was "timestamp with time zone" but I thought it causes the problem and I changed it.

I get this problem in this line:

```
for(let Completation of ACC_IDs.rows) {  //Transfer all Completations Condensed
    const ACC_Copy = `INSERT INTO public.cg_completationscondensed(
                      id_c, userlogin, barcode, quantity, adate)
                      VALUES ('`+idc+`', '`+ulogin+`', '`+Completation.barcode+`', '`+Completation.quantity+`', '`+Completation.adate+`');`;
    await client.query(ACC_Copy);
    const ACC_Delete = `DELETE FROM public.cg_actualcompletationscondensed
                        WHERE id = `+Completation.id+`;`;
    await client.query(ACC_Delete);
  }
```

and in next for loop, because there are operation on date too.

Comment: *Where* in your function do you get that?

Comment: @VLAZ in second for loop, where I commented "Transfer all Completations Condensed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem. I cannot find answer anywhere on the internet so I do it on my own. I added this two lines at the start of the for loop:

```
let date = new Date(Completation.adate);
    date = date.toLocaleDateString() + " " + date.toLocaleTimeString();
```

and then changed db query to:

```
const ACC_Copy = `INSERT INTO public.cg_completationscondensed(
                      id_c, userlogin, barcode, quantity, adate)
                      VALUES ('`+idc+`', '`+ulogin+`', '`+Completation.barcode+`', '`+Completation.quantity+`', '`+date+`');`;
```

and now it works fine, finally!

Answer (score 8):

You are injecting the result of `Date()` type/value to a query. Converting it ISO string solves my issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer, to use `.toISOString()`